# Database services on new vps

Tags: mysql, database, service

There are services like ServerPilot and many others that install on a vps that handle the lamp stack env. I'm wondering if there is a service that does this for databases. I install the service on a fresh vps and that the service would do all the heavy lifting like security, replication, separate read writes, back-ups and monitoring a long with easily setting up private network access for a set fee to use that service on my server.

Looking for a simple service to install on my own fresh vps, not RDS or Google Cloud.

Thank you!

Comment: some questions to answer first: replication between what instances and why do you need it at all? where are you going to store the backups? Are daily dumps sufficient or you need PITR? optimization under what load? how many boxes do you need? what do you mean by 'separate read/writes'? what monitoring metrics are you seeking?  are you familiar with docker? and what's wrong with RDS/GC for your tasks?

Comment: Daily backups are going to be on a storage server. Seperate read/writes would be used for performance, one server would simple write while the other reads. I'm familiar with docker and don't have a team so docker isn't needed. RDS/GC are slow as opposed to having everything on a private network or full stack server as far as performance goes. I'm probably not wording the question correctly because I don't understand the terminology fully. Essentially a service that would do all the heavy lifting with a ux to mange it all.

Answer (score 4):

**What Does ServerPilot Really Do?**

First, ServerPilot deploys complete LAMP stack on your server and that’s including world’s most used web server Apache, PHP5, and MYSQL. To make it even super, ServerPilot also installs and configures Nginx in front of Apache to achieve unbeatable speed and scalability.

Secondly, ServerPilot will secure your server with a firewall. To make it even secure, it will also update your server’s packages and make sure they stay updated all the time to avoid even single bug caused by outdated package.

Thirdly, ServerPilot also offers a premium feature to monitor real-time stats of your server’s performance including CPU, memory, disk space, and more.

**What Does ServerPilot Not Do?**

Meanwhile Serverpilot does not provide features related to installing, configuring and managing email and DNS. In this case you may need third-party DNS server to be able to point your domain to your VPS. Need recommendations? Try CloudFlare, PointHQ, NameCheap, etc.

Also, ServerPilot does not manage your server running other than Ubuntu.

Get more details at : http://www.servermom.org/install-manage-apache-nginx-php-mysql-easiest-serverpilot/1011/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about services, but assuming that your VPS is Ubuntu or some other Debian-based distro, you could perform `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin` on the command line to get your LAMP stack setup. This will setup Apache web server, PHP, and MySQL on your Linux server. Apache and PHP will come working out-of-the-box, and when you install MySQL, by default it asks for a root password to manage the database.

phpMyAdmin would be the key here because instead of doing all your database tasks via the command line, it provides a GUI interface in your web browser to manage databases and tables. To backup your database with phpMyAdmin, see [this article](https://support.managed.com/kb/a2034/how-to-backup-and-or-restore-your-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin.aspx).

With regards to customizations, for the firewall you can simply write a few iptables rules and for the database, you can run scheduled backups of a MySQL database by creating a cron job that runs the following command:`/usr/bin/mysqldump -u dbusername -p'dbpassword' dbname > /path/backup.sql`

Again, this isn't a service, but at least you wouldn't have to pay for any of the tools.

Comment: Is the `^` a typo?

Comment: No, that is supposed to be there.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what does it do?

Comment: phpMyAdmin isn't a service I'm interested in. I more interested in a service that does all the read write replication, back ups, optimization, and networking on a private network with a new vps. Right now I'm using a LAMP env and I would like to separate the database but I don't have enough experience to secure, optimize, and networking. Hence my question. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no ultimate service than can perform all this stuff. However, you can set up this manually:

- Database replication:
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql
- Database backup:
  http://www.ducea.com/2006/05/27/backup-your-mysql-databases-automatically-with-automysqlbackup/
  or
  https://www.backuphowto.info/how-backup-mysql-database-automatically-linux-users
- Database optimization:
  https://www.tecmint.com/mysql-mariadb-performance-tuning-and-optimization/
  and
  http://www.monitis.com/blog/101-tips-to-mysql-tuning-and-optimization/
- And for the networking, this tutorial may be helpful
  http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialNetworking.html